# has_many through with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This are the two models I'm using to query this:

**model 1**

```
 has_many :locks_order_items, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :locks, through: :locks_order_items
```

**model 2**

```
 belongs_to :order_item
 belongs_to :lock
```

**Form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_items, @order_items do |f1| %>
   <% f1.object.locks_order_items.order("locks_order_items.check
   DESC, locks_order_items.id ASC").each do |m| 
      <li> <%= m.lock.name %> </li>
      <input type='hidden' name='order[order_items_attributes][<%= row_count
      %>][locks_order_items_attributes][][lock_id]' value='<%= m.lock_id %>'
      />
   end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the query running, when the form loads:

```
SELECT "locks_order_items".* FROM "locks_order_items" WHERE 
"locks_order_items"."order_item_id" = 4444 ORDER BY 
locks_order_items.check DESC, locks_order_items.id ASC
```

If we have 10 entries in model 2, the above query will run 10 times. I have tried to add includes, but still it's running like that.

Is there any way to  run that in one query with includes?

Comment: I've made some text and format corrections to improve the clarity of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Select, filter and order your models in your controller and not in your views. Your views should simply display whatever they are given.

So, order your models in your controller and use `includes()` to resolve `N+1` queries:

```
@results = YourModel.includes(:locks_order_items).where({your: :query}).
               order("locks_order_items.check DESC, locks_order_items.id ASC")
```

In your views just render your collection.

Comment: i coudn't accomplish this one, i think my scenario is taking as different

Comment: I've just tried to run this in my rails console with my project models. Worked just fine.

Comment: I have update that question also, I was trying like this way model1.includes(:locks_order_items).where("order_id = ?", 133305).order("locks_order_items.check DESC, locks_order_items.id ASC"), so when it runs, one thing is that query running this format
"SELECT "order_items"."id" AS t0_r0, "order_items"."order_id" AS t0_r1", and the second things is, when i am trying to get the lock attritbutes, i couldnt get that